# How can i access to a remote droplet using putty batch scripting with key files?

Tags: command-line, ssh, batch, batch-file, putty

I'm trying to login into my droplet using batch scripting in order to run some command lines.

the problem is I don't know how to access my droplet using a private key with a batch script and putty?

I already PermitRootLogin no in the droplet and AthenticationPassword no also.

so I allowed to log in as a customized username that I already created before on the droplet and just with a private key

how can I pass that key into my batch scripting to let me log in to my droplet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a search i found that:

```
plink.exe -i privateKey.ppk username@hostname -m commands.txt
```

**-i:** to add your private key.
**-m:** to add the file that contains the commands you want to execute.